# Tensorflow - executing a model in production as efficiently as possible

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-serving

I have a semantic-segmentation model created using Keras.

Now I want to use it in production where I need to execute the model on a large folder with 10k-100k images a few times a day. This takes several hours, so every improvement is helpful.

I'm wondering what is the correct way to use it in production. I currently just use `model.predict()` on a created `Sequence`. But everywhere I look I see all kinds of different libraries or technologies that seem relevant.

`Tensorflow-serving`, converting to C, different libraries by intel and others.

I'm wondering what is the bottom-line recommended way to execute a model as production-grade and as efficiently as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure this has a canonical answer — as with many things there are lots of tradeoffs between different choices — but I'll attempt to give an answer.

I've been pretty happy using TensorFlow Serving to do model deployment, with separate services doing the business logic calling those models and doing something with the predictions. That provides a small boost because there won't be as much resource contention — the TensorFlow Serving instances do nothing but run the models. We have them deployed via Kubernetes, and that makes grouping a cluster of TensorFlow Serving instances very easy if you want to scale horizontally as well for more throughput.

You're unlikely to get meaningful improvements by messing around the edges with things like making sure the TensorFlow Serving deployment is compiled with the right flags to use all of Intel's vector instructions. The big boost is running everything in fast C++ code. The one (probably very obvious) way to boost performance is to run the inference on a GPU rather than a CPU. That's going to scale more or less the way you'd expect: the more powerful the GPU, the faster the inference is going to be.

There are probably more involved things you could do to eke our more single percentage point gains. But this strikes a pretty good balance of speed with flexibility. It's definitely a little bit more finicky to have this separate service architecture: if you're not doing something too complicated, it might be easier (if quite a bit slower) to use your models "as-is" in a Python script rather than going to the trouble of setting up TensorFlow serving. On the other hand, the speedup is pretty significant, and it's pretty easy to manage. On the other end of the spectrum, I have no idea what crazy things you could do to eke out more marginal performance gains, but instinct tells me that they're going to be pretty exotic, and therefore pretty difficult to maintain.

Comment: What is the performance gain you received from tensorflow serving?

Comment: I don't have numbers, but the direct speedup is negligible. TensorFlow is already running highly optimized C++ code; the Python stuff is a wrapper. The bigger speedup is going to come from flexibility (e.g., run only the TF model on a GPU, keep Python on CPU), reduced resource contention in the Python code execution, and the ability to scale the TF model horizontally.

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to answer, but I will consider the following orthogonal aspects

1. Is it possible for me to run a model at a lower resolution? If so, resizing an image before running the model -- this should give you X**2 times of speed up, where X is the downsampling factor that you use.
2. Production models are often executed remotely. So understanding your remote machine config is very important. If you only have CPU-only machines, options like OpenVINO typically give more speed-up than the native tensorflow. If you have GPU machines, options like tensorRT can also help you. The actual speed-up is very difficult to estimate, but I would say at least 2x faster.
3. Uploading/downloading a JPEG image instead of PNG or BMP. This should largely reduce your communication time.